# php Soapserver empty php://input

Tags: php, soap

I am setting up a soapserver and for some reason when trying to connect file_get_contents('php://input') is empty.

In Fiddler I can see that the clientprogram is actually sending the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Header><AuthenticationHeader xmlns="http://www.cito.nl/DULTService/"><Username>dult</Username><Password>dult</Password><Brincode>99DE00</Brincode></AuthenticationHeader></soap:Header><soap:Body><DULTValidateCredentials xmlns="http://www.cito.nl/DULTService/" /></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

The soapclient sends two empty calls first, before sending the one above, not sure if that could be related.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Why do you need `php://input` to not be empty? Are you trying to use that instead of `SoapServer`?

Comment: I need to read the xml that is being send, to check the username/password and send the correct response.

Comment: btw if I do $server->handle() the function 'DULTValidateCredentials' is never called either.

Comment: You definitely shouldn't need work with XML requests and responses directly when you're using `SoapServer` or `SoapClient`. I'll see if I can find a PHP + SOAP tutorial.

Comment: Thank you jjok. I use $server->handle(), which always works and calls the appropriate function in the assigned class. In this case however it doesn't. That is why I checked php://input and that is always empty.

Comment: I've found the problem. Another class was doing a redirect, so the xml never arrived at the soap class. Thanks all for your help, much appriciated.